# Apache solr slave is getting replicated before indexing completes

Tags: solr, master-slave

Solr slave is getting replicated before indexing is getting completed. Getting this issue after RELOAD of core and  full indexing.

Master config.

```
 <requestHandler name="/replication" class="solr.ReplicationHandler" >
  <lst name="master">
  <str name="enable">true</str>
  <str name="replicateAfter">optimize</str>
  <str name="confFiles">schema.xml,dataimport.properties,managed-schema,params.json,solr-data-config.xml,stopwords.txt,synonyms.txt</str>
  </lst>
  <int name="maxNumberOfBackups">2</int>
</requestHandler>
```

Slave Config

```
<requestHandler name="/replication" class="solr.ReplicationHandler" >
  <lst name="slave">
    <str name="enable">true</str>
    <str name="masterUrl">http://localhost:8983/solr/master2/replication</str>
    <str name="pollInterval">00:01:00</str>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

Comment: Have you compared the index versions available when the replication happens? Does optimize get called when you commit as well?

Comment: @MatsLindh :- yes we have compared index versions available for searching , when full indexing is going on searchable index for slave changes to new one and on each replication interval data  at slave is getting updated each time with what ever new files are generated while searching.

while doing full indexing following things are selected clean,commit,optimize.

Comment: Add your complete indexing configuration to the question - seeing as you're only replicating on optimize, I'm guessing that might be were your issue is ; that optimizes are getting called too often (check your log to see if that's the case). Also try changing the replicateAfter parameter to just startup - in that case it should _not_ replicate after commit/optimize and re-indexing, only when the core is starting up.